# how to convert xml files into html in .NET

Tags: xml, xslt

```
 Xml1.Visible = true;
        ltlTutorial.Visible = false;
        string xmlString = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("XMLFile1.xml"));
        Xml1.DocumentContent = xmlString;            
        Xml1.TransformSource = Server.MapPath("XSLTFile1.xslt");
```

how to convert xml files into html in .NET? (i.e., once xml file is uploaded and on clicking button it should convert into html file)
any one knows please help me with this?

Comment: Where does the database come into this?  Do you just mean that the XML document's stored in a database but you have some other code to fetch the value from the database and perform the XSLT against it?  If so, what language is that other code written in?  If not, what database are you using (in case it's some database with built in XSLT support... though not sure if such a DB exists...).  Also, what bit are you struggling with?  Reading the XML from the database, performing the XSLT against it, or returning the result?

Comment: i thought of using database by bringing tag VALUES INTO database, now i got to know its not working. Please help me with this how to convert XML to HTML file. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using .Net, then you probably want to use XSLTCompiledTransform. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.110).aspx